# Rails 4 Accept nested attributes with has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, accepts-nested-attributes

I have a question about Rails Nested Attributes.
I'm using Rails 4 and have this model:

```
model Location
 has_one parking_photo
 has_many cod_photos
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :parking_photo
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :cod_photos
end
```

When I use for example:
`Location.find(100).update(cod_photo_ids: [1,2,3])` it works.

But `Location.find(100).update(parking_photo_id: 1)` doesn't works.

I don't know what difference between nested attributes has_one and has_many.

Or do we have any solution for my case, when I already have child object and want to link the parent to the child and don't want to use child update.

Thank you.

Comment: You could try `Location.find(100).update( parking_photo: ParkingPhoto.find(1) )` that should change the `location_id` in the child object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with nested attributes. In fact you're not even using nested attributes at all in these examples.

In this example:

```
Location.find(100).update(cod_photo_ids: [1,2,3])
```

This will work even if you comment out `accepts_nested_attributes_for :cod_photos` as the `cod_photo_ids=` setter is created by `has_many :cod_photos`.

In the other example you're using `has_one` where you should be using `belongs_to` or are just generally confused about how you should be modeling the association. `has_one` places the foreign key on the `parking_photos` table.

If you want to place the `parking_photo_id` on the `locations` table you would use `belongs_to`:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parking_photo
  # ...
end

class ParkingPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location # references  locations.parking_photo_id
end
```

Of course you also need a migration to actually add the `locations.parking_photo_id` column. I would really suggest you forget about nested attributes for the moment and just figure out the basics [of how assocations work in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/association_basics.html).

If you really want to have the inverse relationship and put `location_id` on `parking_photos` you would set it up like so:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :parking_photo
  # ...
end

class ParkingPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  validates_uniqueness_of :location_id
end
```

And you could reassign a photo by:

```
Location.find(100).parking_photo.update(location_id: 1)
```